# How to deal with different countdown in listview

Tags: flutter, dart

I have multiple Countdown widgets in a listview.builder.
When I refresh the list I want to reset timer of all widgets according to the new values returned in the list.
I had an idea is to make a function in the countdown that setState of it. Is there a way to specify unique key for each widget and then call it with it's key ? I tried ValueKey() but can't call the widget by it's valueKey.

It is a global question no code needed. If you have any idea or surpassed this problem please help me.Another approach or solution is appreciated.

Comment: Post some of the code that you wrote, so it can be copied easily and minimal to reproduce, in order for the users who can potentially answer your question, not spend extra time writing this code which you actually wrote. Also, you might be implementing something the wrong way, and the answer can be more beneficial and educational for the person asking.